# Replace Woocommerce product stock status with a custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

Does anybody know some example filter to fill the stock status text with value from custom field?

DB:

```
Product 1, stock_status = in-stock, stock_status_custom = '5 days'
Product 2, stock_status = in-stock, stock_status_custom = '10 days'
```

CODE:

```
function customGetStockTextForProduct($productId){
  return get_field('stock_status_custom', $productId);
}
add_filter('customGetStockTextForProduct', 'customGetStockTextForProduct');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `woocommerce_get_availability` filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function custom_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $custom_text = get_field( 'stock_status_custom', $product->get_id());

    if( ! empty($custom_text) )
        $availability['availability'] = $custom_text;

    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.